# Why my url redirect to another one?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I put a rule to rewrite some links.

This url

```
http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/images/servane/ms-servane-5_n_nette_h540.jpg
```

redirects to

```
http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/main/wp-content/themes/MS-MangoBerry/timthumb.php?src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/steffiandmihanta/main/wp-content/gallery/servane/ms-servane-5_n_nette.jpg&q=100&h=540
```

My htaccess is :

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)_h(.*).jpg$ http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/main/wp-content/themes/MS-MangoBerry/timthumb.php?src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/steffiandmihanta/main/wp-content/gallery/$1.jpg&q=100&h=$2 [NC,L]
```

How can I modify it not to redirect to the ugly url ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)_h(.*).jpg$ http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/main/wp-content/themes/MS-MangoBerry/timthumb.php?src=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/steffiandmihanta/main/wp-content/gallery/$1.jpg&q=100&h=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I changed `[NC,L]` to `[L,QSA]` but the pretty link always redirects to the ugly link